# sharp edges on imported geometry

Tags: materials, faces, geometry

I'm getting some strange sharp edges on imported models when viewing the material.

Things I've tried:

- normals are facing the correct way
- shade smooth is on
- clean up/ merge vertices
- no sharps/seams

[image: material]

[image: solid]

Another Odd thing is that when I change faces tris to quads, the edges still remain

None of the material maps have any odd shading

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The normal map needed to be changed to **colorspace : non-color**, and now the model appears smooth.